# How do I check if a range of SpecialCells contains cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I ran into an edge case in one of my spreadsheets recently. I have a loop going over all visible cells in a table:

```
For Each c In ws.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    ...
Next c
```

Normally there will always be a few items visible, but in an edge case none were, which generated an error in my code:

> Run-time error '1004': No cells were found

I tried wrapping the for-loop in an if-statement

```
If ws.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 0 Then
```

But this generates the same error. Similarly if I check if the range is nothing.

How do I go about checking if there are visible cells in the filtered table?

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution, I used the solution shown below, where `On Error Resume Next` causes the error to be skipped, allowing me to check if a range has been assigned to the variable `rng` afterwards.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim c As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set rng = ws.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    For Each c In rng
        ...
    Next c
End If
```

I suppose a better solution might be creating a proper error handler for the function, as the current implementation is kinda ugly...

Answer (score 0):

I would use a helper function to which you pass the listobject

```vb
Private Function hasVisibleRows(lo As ListObject) As Boolean

If lo.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function

On Error Resume Next
hasVisibleRows = lo.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 0
On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

This is one of the rare cases where `on error resume next` is valid, as there is no other way to check for visible rows.

But I would always put the check in a separate function.